# Does Application Type (OpenID Connect) correspond to Client Type (OAuth 2.0)?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid

"[OpenID Connect Dynamic Client Registration 1.0](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html), [2. Client Metadata](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html#ClientMetadata)" has an entry named **application_type**, whose defined values are **native** and **web**.

```
application_type
   OPTIONAL. Kind of the application. The default, if omitted, is web.
   The defined values are native or web. Web Clients using the OAuth
   Implicit Grant Type MUST only register URLs using the https scheme
   as redirect_uris; they MUST NOT use localhost as the hostname. Native
   Clients MUST only register redirect_uris using custom URI schemes or
   URLs using the http: scheme with localhost as the hostname.
   Authorization Servers MAY place additional constraints on Native
   Clients. Authorization Servers MAY reject Redirection URI values
   using the http scheme, other than the localhost case for Native
   Clients. The Authorization Server MUST verify that all the registered 
   redirect_uris conform to these constraints. This prevents sharing a
   Client ID across different types of Clients.
```

Do these defined values correspond to **public** and **confidential** described in "[RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (OAuth 2.0), [2.1. Client Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1)"?

```
OAuth defines two client types, based on their ability to
authenticate securely with the authorization server (i.e., ability to
maintain the confidentiality of their client credentials):

confidential
   Clients capable of maintaining the confidentiality of their
   credentials (e.g., client implemented on a secure server with
   restricted access to the client credentials), or capable of secure
   client authentication using other means.

public
   Clients incapable of maintaining the confidentiality of their
   credentials (e.g., clients executing on the device used by the
   resource owner, such as an installed native application or a web
   browser-based application), and incapable of secure client
   authentication via any other means.
```

If not, why doesn't the specification (OpenID Connect Dynamic Client Registration 1.0) have an entry to specify a client type? Is there any way to specify a client type (public or confidential) at the [client registration endpoint](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html#ClientRegistration)?

Answer (score 6):

If "***Native Clients***" in "[OpenID Connect Dynamic Client Registration 1.0](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html), [2. Client Metadata](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html#ClientMetadata)" means "***native application***" in "[RFC 6749 (OAuth 2.0)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), [2.1 Client Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1)" (yes it apparently does), *Native Clients* are always ***public*** clients.

If "***Web Clients***" in "[OpenID Connect Dynamic Client Registration 1.0](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html), [2. Client Metadata](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html#ClientMetadata)" means "***web application***" in "[RFC 6749 (OAuth 2.0)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), [2.1 Client Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1)" but does not include "***user-agent-based application***", *Web Clients* are always ***confidential*** clients.

Using the above interpretation, *application_type=native* and *application_type=web* correspond to *public* and *confidential*, respectively.

However, the requirement of application_type:

```
Web Clients using the OAuth Implicit Grant Type MUST only
register URLs using the https scheme as redirect_uris; they
MUST NOT use localhost as the hostname. Native Clients MUST
only register redirect_uris using custom URI schemes or URLs
using the http: scheme with localhost as the hostname.
```

is irrelevant to whether or not clients are "*capable of maintaining the confidentiality of their credentials*" (from RFC 6749). In other words, redirect URIs are irrelevant to how to authenticate clients. Therefore, it sounds to me that Application Type and Client Type are different concepts.

It is weird that all ***OAuth 2.0 clients*** must comply with either of the 'redirect_uris' requirements (one is for *Web Clients* and the other is for *Native Clients*), so probably it is inappropriate that 'web' is used as the default value when application_type is omitted. IMHO, neither of 'native' nor 'web' should be assumed when application_type is omitted. But, I may be missing something. Is there any reason to impose the 'redirect_uris' requirements on all ***OpenID Connect clients***?

Anyway, my conclusion is that Application Type and Client Type are different. And I hope that client_type (public or confidential) is added to the list of Client Metadata and that neither of 'native' nor 'web' is used as the default value when application_type is not contained in [client registration requests](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html#RegistrationRequest).